# Additional mouse buttons do not work with CS:GO

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, mouse

I've been trying to map the buttons on my Roccat Tyon mouse to functions in CS:GO, but it doesn't seem to work. Whether I use Xinput or Dinput (Roccat software) doesn't matter, CS:GO only recognizes the native mouse buttons (left, right & middle click & scroll wheel) and the buttons that are mapped to other keys like Home, PageDn etc.

Help would be appreciated, I've tried setting it as a controller, turning on and off raw input, but nothing seems to work. :(

~Pwuts

Comment: did you used the macro function in the roccat driver?

Comment: I wanted to try that but there are only macro's for CS:Source and CS 1.6

Comment: *edit* I followed Gerret's instructions and now it works. I just can't figure out how I can "press and hold" buttons: the key which they trigger only gets "pressed" once by the macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like CS:GO is not able to recognize the buttons of your mouse. What you can do is to create some macros in your mouse driver.

**Keep in mind that I am using the driver tool for the Kone[+] and your driver window may look different from mine. If someone has the same problem but is using a different mouse you can go ahead and try reproducing the same for your driver.**

For the first step you have to create a new macro set where you can collect all your CS:GO macros. Just open your driver and execute this 4 steps below.

[image]
<sub>Click on the Image to enlarge it</sub>

After that, select your created macro set and press the new button at the left bottom. To assign something to that macro you press the start record button and **press the button which you would use without the mouse**. For example the number 3 for the knife.

If you have all function assigned, press the ok button to save your changes. (Keep in mind that you can create more complex things in the macro manager. You also can use the advanced editor.)

[image]

The last step is to assign the created macros to a button on your mouse. But before you go ahead and assign a button you should keep in mind that you lose that function on that button.

So you should add all your CS:GO function to a new mouse profile and switch to that profile if you playing CS:GO.

*Pro tip: You can assign a profile to the game so everytime you start CS:GO the profile is selected automatically. If you press the WP button this profile is selected automatically if you change to windows.*

To assign the function to a button you just select the number of the button you want the function to be and select your macro on there.

[image]

Comment: thank you :) It's so simple I'm kind of ashamed that I didn't think of looking into this myself, but thx ;)